# How to create an ISO from a file (not a directory)

Tags: disk-utility, vmware, iso

I'm trying to perform some testing on old platforms. In this case, its Fedora 1 (circa 2002 or 2003). The VM software (VMware and VirtualBox) can't handle distros that old, so the guests don't have a network card.

I found I could transfer stuff to them through the CD Rom drive. However, when I attempt to build an ISO with a file I am trying to transfer:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -o ~/image.iso ~/make-4.1.tar.gz -iso -joliet
Creating hybrid image...

hdiutil: makehybrid failed - Operation not permitted
```

I also tried with `create`, but that result in an error, too:

```
hdiutil create -ov ~/make-4.1.tar.gz  -iso -joliet
hdiutil: create: unknown option "-iso"
Usage:  hdiutil create <sizespec> [options] <imagepath>
    hdiutil create -help
```

I've also tried with and without the option ***`makehybrid`***.

How do I create an ISO of a file (and not a directory)?

---

I want to avoid unzipping and then building the ISO because filenames and permissions are changed (This is older software that's not as stable as it is today).

Comment: Did you try wrapping your command with `sudo`? It may be that `hdiutil` is trying to write temp-files to a place were it does not have access.

Comment: The source for hdiutil -makehybrid needs to be a directory or disk image (see manpage); maybe try extracting the archive with -p option passed to tar to preserve permissions/owners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create an ISO image from a non-image file. *hdiutil* and especially *hdiutil makehybrid* expect an image or a directory (not necessarily containing files!).

---

But you don't have to unzip/unarchive anything. Just create a folder with the name *MAKE*, move the gz file into it and then enter `hdiutil makehybrid -o ~/make.iso ~/MAKE -iso -joliet`. The resulting mounted image just contains the file *make-4.1.tar.gz*.

The permissions of the iso mounted to the file system of the Fedora VM should then be:

```
# ls -al /dev/cdrom*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 [date] /dev/cdrom -> devicename #e.g. sr0 or something similar, it depends on your distro and the /etc/fstab file inside the VM
```

and the file *make-4.1.tar.gz* "inside" is world readable.

After copying the gz file to your user folder in the VM, unarchive/unzip it.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce Klanomath's answer to a recipe:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/MAKE
rm -f ./make.iso
cp make-4.1.tar.gz /tmp/MAKE/make-4.1.tar.gz
hdiutil makehybrid -o ./make.iso /tmp/MAKE/ -iso -joliet
```

Then, mount `make.iso` in the virtual machine.

Be aware of the [race conditions](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/compsystems/1996/spr_bishop.pdf) when using `/tmp`. They are not a worry to me because this is for local testing, and not production.